# Gnumeric Python plugin : service file_opener and file_saver

Tags: python, gnome, pygobject, gnumeric

Is it possible to write a gnumeric python plugin for the `file_opener` and `file_saver` service?

It seems implemented in the python-loader plugin, there are corresponding sections in the [Gnome documentation](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnumeric/tree/plugins/python-loader/python-loader.c).

But the *example* plugin [gnome-glossary](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnumeric/tree/plugins/gnome-glossary), which is python `file_saver` plugin, raises an error `ImportError: No module named gsf` and I can't write in the output object given by the API:

```
def so_file_save(wb, output):
    output.props.write("toto")
```

produces the error :

```
Exception Python (<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> : 'gobject.GProps' object has no attribute 'write')
```

And this gobject.GProps object claim to be of `__gtype__ : GsfOutputStdio`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python bindings for 'libgsf' are unsupported since a long time ago.  As you can read in the old [README-python](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libgsf/tree/python/README-python?id=d6cf9a1a14809504c8d287de8a99e62ddfbba15f):

> I wrote these bindings in 2002, and they haven't been updated since.
>   They were never part of a standard build, but it was possible to build
>   them by following the instructions below. It will probably take some
>   work to make them work with current versions of autotools and
>   pygobject. Bindings would have to be revalidated, and extended to
>   match the current API of libgsf.
>
> I do not plan to do further work on these bindings. If anybody wants
>   to pick them up, please feel free.
>
> Jon K Hellan [...] 2006-02-24

That explaines why `gnome-glossary` fails.  Also, it seems to be a problem with the parameter output, which is shown as a `GObject`, but not as `GsfOutputStdio` (you only can see the properties, but you do not have access to any method.

This is not the solution you are looking for, but an attempt of explanation of what you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks, you confirm my fears. My project will wait until I have more time ; or I will take my chances with the heavy and buggish LibreOffice.